# How do I simplify the sum of the image?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, summation

How do I simplify the sum of the image? I am studying the probability function of order statics X(i). It differentiates the distribution function, but I don't know how to simplify the sum to obtain the result of the image.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final equation is suggesting that the first term of the first sum is *the only man standing*. That's indeed the case. For the first sum do the following:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{j=i}^n\dbinom{n}{j}jf(x)(F(x))^{j-1}(1-F(x))^{n-j} &= \dbinom{n}{i}if(x)(F(x))^{i-1}(1-F(x))^{n-i}\\
&\quad + \sum_{j=i}^n\dbinom{n}{j+1}(j+1)f(x)(F(x))^{j}(1-F(x))^{n-j-1}.
\end{align*}
(Note the subtle change of index in the sum). Now you just need to prove that 
$$
\dbinom{n}{j+1}(j+1)=\dbinom{n}{j}(n-j).
$$

Comment: Perfect, thanks!